# Chrome/Chromium shows HTTP header in page content along with some junk

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have tried asking solution for this everywhere , looks like nobody has this problem but me. Whenever I visit website like twitter/Flickr/Ebay , it shows the HTTP header in the page content. If this has happened to you and you've found a solution ,please reply. I desperately need to use chorme,can't bear the utter slow Firefox.

Ive tagged both Google-Chrome and Chromium as this happens in both.

[image]

Comment: is it any extension/addon that you might be  using in both browsers ?

Comment: Also, which version of Chrome ?

Comment: @Shark No,its not because of any addon , as it used to happen even before installing any extensions.
@Sathya Google Chrome 9.0.597.44 (Official Build 70439) beta

Comment: Try going to `chrome://net-internals/view-cache/http://twitter.com/sridarshan` and see what it says the headers are. Or go to the Developer Tools, Resources page, and dig into the items and headers there. You might find additional headers or clues about what's causing the issue. (For example, perhaps a proxy server or firewall/security program is incorrectly modifying the response.)

Comment: additional info: this happens only in chrome browser ,ff works great!

Comment: @Bavi_H 
" Failed to read resourceview-cache/http://twitter.com/sridarshan "